# How to drawtext colon with pts gmtime using ffmpeg?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am adding timestamp to video using FFMPEG where i am using below command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=roboto.ttf:fontsize=36:fontcolor=yellow:text='%{pts\:gmtime\:1575526882\:%d/%m/%y %H:%M}'" -preset ultrafast -f mp4 output.mp4
```

in this command i am using `:` between %H and %M in `text` attribute of `drawtext`

```
text='%{pts\:gmtime\:1575526882\:%d/%m/%y %H:%M}'
```

because i want to print time like this `06:25`

it show me this error:

> Unterminated %{} near '{pts:gmtime:1575526882:%d/%m/%y %H'

how can i print `:` between `%H` and `%M` where `%H` is for hours and `%M` is for minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy method is to use `%R`:

```
text='%{pts\:gmtime\:1575526882\:%d/%m/%y %R}'
```

Otherwise you'll have to deal with the annoyance of escaping:

```
text='%{pts\:gmtime\:1575526882\:%d/%m/%y %H\\\\\:%M}'
```

You may have to vary the number of backslashes depending on your environment.

Comment: (1). When i am using %R(Lazy Method) it's taking so much time to add timestamp to video (2). When i am using \\\\\% it will show me error(%pts require at most 3 argument)

Comment: I finally found ans. you suggest me to use \\\\\%(5 backslash). but instead of \\\\\%(5 backslash) i am using \\\%(3 backslash) and it's working.

Comment: @MilanTejani Edited. 3 backslash did not work for me in Linux bash. I had to use 5 so that's what I used for the answer. For me using `%R` took the same amount of time as using `%H\\\\\:%M`: I don't see how it would affect encoding time, but I don't have access to Android to test it.

Comment: thank you for your clarification and clearing my doubts